# Outbound SSH Connection Refused

Tags: linux, networking, router, ssh

I'm working on integrating Ansible to a project to interface with Cisco routers/switches. My issue doesn't seem related to Ansible or my configuration itself, however, as I'm finding if I manually attempt an SSH connection to a device it is also refused.

Here is the scenario:

- Host: Red Hat Linux Box
- Target: Cisco Router with hostname 0042router (tested with IPs)

My **Ansible command** is as follows:

```
ansible all -m raw -a "executable='' sh cdp neigh" -i hosts
```

My **hosts** list:

```
[routers]
router_one ansible_host = 0042router
```

When running this I'm met with the following **output**:

```
router_one | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 0042router port 22: Connection refused\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I can attempt a ping the same way from **Ansible**:

```
ansible all -m ping -i hosts
```

Which outputs the same message, but oddly **I can ping the router fine from my server**:

```
PING 0042router.company.com (10.x.xx.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 0042router.company.com (10.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=247 time=8.28 ms
64 bytes from 0042router.company.com (10.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=2 ttl=247 time=8.12 ms
64 bytes from 0042router.company.com (10.x.xx.xxx): icmp_seq=3 ttl=247 time=8.03 ms
```

However **I cannot SSH to the router** from my server's shell:

```
ssh: connect to host 0042router port 22: Connection refused
```

I've found that **Ansible** does not us ICMP based pinging, however, so this could make sense why I cannot accomplish a ping from Ansible but can from the server, but I'm unsure what could be blocking outbound SSH connections.

What should I look for? I can access 0042router via SSH2 on port 22 from SecureCRT without any issue as well.

---

**Post-Question Discovery**

- My `/etc/hosts.deny` is not denying anything.

Comment: Can you ssh from the command line to the router?  If not, fix that first.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that. Added "from shell" to be more clear. I believe its a subnet issue, but will leave this up until I can confirm.

Comment: Try running ansible with more verbosity.  `ansible -vvv`.  Also, why use `raw:` instead of `ios_command:` or the other various network modules?

Comment: I've only just started using here, I do not know the capabilities yet. Nonetheless, running ansible with more verbosity will just give me more ways to say the connection was refused. Its not a ansible issue, that's just there for context. I cannot SSH outbound at all & just curious of anything on the OS layer that could block the connection.

Comment: Could it just be you don't have the ssh certificates configured properly?

Comment: Not out of the realm of possibility here, but this is a fresh instance created from a template with the same configurations as other servers able to reach. How might I check this?

Comment: Connection refused means that either there is no sshd listening, it might be listening on a different port or it is listening on a different interface. It can also mean there is a ip acl refusing the connection on the router, on your host, on any router/firewall in between.

Comment: On the OS layer, what can you think of?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart certificate problems do not result in connection refused (as long as the sshd does not terminate on startup because of them)